# Replace string containing slash using SED command

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying the below code to replace the string `/IRM/I` with `E/IRM/I` but am getting the file processed with no error and no transformation. I assume I'm using the cancel character incorrectly to allow the forward slash. Any help is much appreciated.

```
sed -i '/\/IRM\/IE\/IRM\/I/g'
```

Comment: BTW, if you aren't passing a filename, you shouldn't be using the `-i` argument to `sed`.

Comment: sorry, I am passing a filename, I just left it off the code. I am also changing other strings successfully but non contain a forward slash like this last one

Comment: BTW, if you *do* want to keep `/` as your sigil, you need to add escapes only before the forward slashes that should be treated as literal data, and leave it out otherwise. So that would be `sed -e 's/\/IRM\/I/E\/IRM\/I/g'` -- but it's much cleaner and more readable to just pick a different sigil entirely, or for that matter a tool other than `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` command needs to specify an operation (like `s` to replace), and that operation requires a sigil. You don't need to use a slash as that sigil.

```
printf '%s\n' 'This is a test: </IRM/I>' | \
  sed -e 's@/IRM/I@E/IRM/I@g'
```

...correctly emits as output:

```
This is a test: <E/IRM/I>
```

Note that we added a `s` at the beginning of your `sed` expression, and followed it up with a `@` -- a sigil that isn't contained anywhere in the source or replacement strings, so you don't need to escape it as you would `/`.

Comment: BTW, note that this is flagged "community wiki" -- that's to avoid gaining reputation points for answering a known duplicate.

Comment: Appreciate the quick help, this worked on my end!